# Set CKeditor data in the textarea with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, ckeditor5

I have problem to set data in the ckeditor textarea. For example I need to set data `<p><strong>Tilte</strong></p><p><i>123</i></p>` in the textarea when I've clicked the `save` button, then the data will show in the textarea.

Below is I want the expected result:

[image: output]

Below is my coding that I've tried, I've used this method  `CKEDITOR.instances[agenda_mesyuarat].setData(testing);` but it cannot work.

```js
let theEditor;

    ClassicEditor
      .create(document.querySelector('#agenda_mesyuarat'))
      .then(editor => {
        theEditor = editor;

      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });


    function getDataFromTheEditor() {
      return theEditor.getData();
    }
    
 function send_1() {
  var testing = "<p><strong>Tilte</strong></p><p><i>123</i></p>";
  CKEDITOR.instances[agenda_mesyuarat].setData(testing);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/10.0.1/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>

<textarea class="form-control" name="agenda_mesyuarat" id="agenda_mesyuarat" value="" title="Agenda Mesyuarat"></textarea><br><br>

<button type="button" id="btn_save" value="Save" onclick="send_1()">Save</button>
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are assigning editor instance to theEditor, you can directly use it to set data in ckeditor.

```js
let theEditor;

    ClassicEditor
      .create(document.querySelector('#agenda_mesyuarat'))
      .then(editor => {
        theEditor = editor;

      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });


    function getDataFromTheEditor() {
      return theEditor.getData();
    }
    
 function send_1() {
  var testing = "<p><strong>Tilte</strong></p><p><i>123</i></p>";
  theEditor.setData(testing);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/10.0.1/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>

<textarea class="form-control" name="agenda_mesyuarat" id="agenda_mesyuarat" value="" title="Agenda Mesyuarat"></textarea><br><br>

<button type="button" id="btn_save" value="Save" onclick="send_1()">Save</button>
```